# Parametric test with generic methods

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

In NUnit 2.5 you can do this:

```
[TestCase(1,5,7)]
public void TestRowTest(int i, int j, int k)
{
  Assert.AreEqual(13, i+j+k);
}
```

You can do parametric test.

But I wonder whether you can do this or not, parametric test with generic test method? I.e.:

```
[TestCase <int>("Message")]
public void TestRowTestGeneric<T>(string msg)
{
  Assert.AreEqual(5, ConvertStrToGenericParameter<T>(msg));
}
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is the quote from the release note of NUnit 2.5 [link text](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5)

> Parameterized test methods may be
>   generic. NUnit will deduce the correct
>   implementation to use based on the
>   types of the parameters provided.
>   Generic test methods are supported in
>   both generic and non-generic clases.

According to this, it is possible to have generic test method in non-generic class. How?

I don't quite understand Jeff's comment. In .net generics is both compile-time and run-time. We can use the reflection to find out the test case attribute associated with a method, find out the generic parameter, and again use reflection to call the generic method. It will work, no?

Update: OK, I now know how and hope it is not too late. You need the generic type to be in the parameter list. For example:

```
[TestCase((int)5, "5")]
[TestCase((double)2.3, "2.3")]
public void TestRowTestGeneric<T>(T value, string msg)
{
  Assert.AreEqual(value, ConvertStrToGenericParameter<T>(msg));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make custom GenericTestCaseAttribute

```
    [Test]
    [GenericTestCase(typeof(MyClass) ,"Some response", TestName = "Test1")]
    [GenericTestCase(typeof(MyClass1) ,"Some response", TestName = "Test2")]
    public void MapWithInitTest<T>(string expectedResponse)
    {
        // Arrange

        // Act
        var response = MyClassUnderTest.MyMethod<T>();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResponse, response);
    }
```

Here is implementation of GenericTestCaseAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class GenericTestCaseAttribute : TestCaseAttribute, ITestBuilder
{
    private readonly Type _type;
    public GenericTestCaseAttribute(Type type, params object[] arguments) : base(arguments)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    IEnumerable<TestMethod> ITestBuilder.BuildFrom(IMethodInfo method, Test suite)
    {
        if (method.IsGenericMethodDefinition && _type != null)
        {
            var gm = method.MakeGenericMethod(_type);
            return BuildFrom(gm, suite);
        }
        return BuildFrom(method, suite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I've been struggling for days how to do this nicely and your answer helped me finally get it right!

Comment: This is excellent. I can't wait for this to go through pull request review!

Answer (score 2):

Create a private method and call that:

```
    [Test]
    public void TypeATest()
    {
        MyTest<TypeA>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TypeBTest()
    {
        MyTest<TypeB>();
    }

    private void MyTest<T>()
    {
        // do test.
    }
```

Comment: I had to use this method for my test that looked like this: [TestCase(new float[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new float[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, true)] public void AbleToCompareEqualArrays(T[] ar1, T[] ar2, bool expectedValue)

Comment: Nice answer. It's much better than creating custom attributes (imho)