# NUnit 3 with generics

Tags: c#, generics, testing, nunit

I saw this post here [Parametric test with generic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801153/nunit-parametric-test-with-generic-methods) for NUnit 2.5:

```
[TestCase((int)5, "5")]
[TestCase((double)2.3, "2.3")]
public void TestRowTestGeneric<T>(T value, string msg)
{
   Assert.AreEqual(value, ConvertStrToGenericParameter<T>(msg));
}
```

But looks it's not working anymore for NUnit 3.0?

What would be the right way for this scenario?

```
[Test]
[TestCase(0)]
[TestCase(FakeEnum.DefaultValue)]
public void should_expect_T_value<T>(T expectedValue)
{
   var result = DoStuff<T>();
   Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, result);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: My answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40619328/1412592 works fine for NUnit 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Generic parametric tests still work fine in 3.0.  The following test is passing:

```
[Test]
// These are all "zero" values.
[TestCase(0, true)]
[TestCase(TypeCode.Empty, true)]
[TestCase(StringComparison.CurrentCulture, true)]
// These are not
[TestCase(TypeCode.Byte, false)]
[TestCase(StringComparison.InvariantCulture, false)]
public void Value_IsEquivalentTo_Zero<T>(T value, bool expectedResult)
{
    // Quick n dirty conversion of 0 to T
    T zero = (T)(object)0;
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, value.Equals(zero));
}
```

Comment: I've tried copying and pasting the code, and the tests would simply just not run.

I am using VS2015. Would it have anything to do with the environment?

Comment: Possibly. I'm on NUnit 3.0, VS2015, and using NUnit3 Test Adapter 3.0.7 extension to run them tests.

Comment: Hey NPras, thanks for ur help.

Seriously im getting mad. Obviously at this stage, I had to do it in a different way, but I'm still curious why is not even running the test or giving any exception message.

I've just created a blank solution, targeting framework 4.5, addling the last nuget package of NUnit, wht NUnit3 Test Adapter 3.0.7, copying the same tests as above, and still wont do anything when running the tests.

Any ideas why...?

Comment: That's a head-scratcher for sure. Did the Test Explorer window pick up the tests, but refused to run them?  
Also, I have Test Adapter 2 and 3 both installed, and have noticed on the output window that 2 tried to run the test, failed, then 3 kicked in.

Comment: Just tried it out with a clean install and just TestAdapter 3 installed, still works fine. I'm sorry, I don't know what else it could be.. VS version? Was it a clean install or upgraded from RC? Other extensions interfering?

Comment: Hi NPras. Thanks for ur help again. I'm not sure. It's a clean machine. Jst new vs 2015, last package and last NUnit extension. It actually picks up the test, but when u run it, it won't do anything, jst as if it didnt exist, or as if would have ignored it.

There must be some specific configuration that may be causing it to not be run.