# How can I test the set of my method exceptions through one test only?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

NUnit 3, VS2015
I want to test exception types of my method through `TestCase` attributes using, but `NUnit3TestAdapter` doesn't see my test in VS2015 (my class is `public`):

```
[TestCase(null, typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
[TestCase("", typeof(ArgumentException))]
[TestCase(" ", typeof(ArgumentException))]
[TestCase(" \t \t ", typeof(ArgumentException))]
[TestCase("< !!!>", typeof(FileNotFoundException))]
public void InvalidFilePath_ThrowsException<T>(string name, 
    T exception_type) where T : Exception {

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Assert.Throws<T>(() => ModelFactory.Current.CreateDocument(name, 
        dict));
}
```

Even more: at this case `NUnit3TestAdapter` doesn't see my all tests... But if I comment this test then `NUnit3TestAdapter` sees other tests:

```
// [TestCase(null, typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
// [TestCase("", typeof(ArgumentException))]
// [TestCase(" ", typeof(ArgumentException))]
// [TestCase(" \t \t ", typeof(ArgumentException))]
// [TestCase("<!!!>", typeof(FileNotFoundException))]
// public void InvalidFilePath_ThrowsException<T>(string name,
//    T exception_type) where T : Exception {

//    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//    Assert.Throws<T>(() => ModelFactory.Current.CreateDocument(name,
//        dict));
//}

[Test]
public void InvalidFilePath_ThrowsException_01() {

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => ModelFactory.Current
    .CreateDocument(null, dict));
}

[Test]
public void InvalidFilePath_ThrowsException_02() {

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => ModelFactory.Current
    .CreateDocument("", dict));
}

[Test]
public void InvalidFilePath_ThrowsException_03() {

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => ModelFactory.Current
    .CreateDocument(" ", dict));
}

[Test]
public void InvalidFilePath_ThrowsException_04() {

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => ModelFactory.Current
    .CreateDocument(" \t \t ", dict));
}

[Test]
public void InvalidFilePath_ThrowsException_05() {

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Assert.Throws<FileNotFoundException>(() => ModelFactory.Current
    .CreateDocument("<!!!>", dict));
}
```

How can I solve it? I wouldn't like to create five separate tests...

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801153/parametric-test-with-generic-methods

Comment: How that info can help me at my case?

Comment: Posted an answer

Comment: Deleted my answer, since it had non-constant values in the attributes.

Comment: "Deleted" == "I have deleted", sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the test method is generic. Instead of using the generic `Assert.Throws<T>`, use the overload that accepts an exception type:

```
[TestCase(null, typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
[TestCase("", typeof(ArgumentException))]
[TestCase(" ", typeof(ArgumentException))]
[TestCase(" \t \t ", typeof(ArgumentException))]
[TestCase("< !!!>", typeof(FileNotFoundException))]
public void InvalidFilePath_ThrowsException(string name, Type exceptionType) 
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();    
    Assert.Throws(exceptionType, () => ModelFactory.Current.CreateDocument(name, dict));
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it's surprising to me that the generic version doesn't work. You might try reversing the arguments so that the exception type comes first. I'd be curious to know what happens.

Comment: Ah! Never mind. It's not a valid use of generic because the method takes an exception Type, not an instance of an exception. Turns out to be an easy mistake to make. :-)